# Why does my button not perform it's function until after other function is performed

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm not sure which part of the code to show in order to explain my situation. But as stated in the title, after the WPF window has been initialized, and the createSheetbutton is clicked to simply display text for example. Nothing occurs until after another function has occurred.

The code below is the button click event which does nothing when called.

```cs
private void CreateSheetButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TaskDialog.Show("Me", "This is in the click event");
}
```

Here is the snippet of the code that has to be called before the click event fires. Not sure why this is happening.

```cs
private async void StartTask_Run()
{
    var progress = new Progress<int>(value => progressBar.Value = value);
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        DisableItems();
        WorkSheetName = GetWorkSheetName();
        StatusText("Connecting to document");
        ((IProgress<int>)progress).Report(5);
        var sourceFile = ExcelSource.OpenExcelFile(FilePath);
        StatusText("Getting Worksheet...");
        ((IProgress<int>)progress).Report(20);
        var sourceWorkSheet = ExcelSource.GetWorkSheet(sourceFile.Item1, sourceFile.Item2, WorkSheetName);  //instantiating the object.
        StatusText("Getting cells count...");
        ((IProgress<int>)progress).Report(30);
        var doc_Max = ExcelSource.GetDocRow_Col(sourceWorkSheet.Item1);
        StatusText("Determining maximum cells with data...");
        ((IProgress<int>)progress).Report(40);
        var maxRow_Col = ExcelSource.GetMaxRow_Col(sourceWorkSheet.Item1, doc_Max.Item1, doc_Max.Item2);
        int maxRowCount = maxRow_Col.Item1;
        int maxColCount = maxRow_Col.Item2;
        StatusText("Compilling data...");
        ((IProgress<int>)progress).Report(60);
        string[,] itemsArr = ExcelSource.GetItems(sourceWorkSheet.Item1, maxRow_Col);
        StatusText("Processing information to view..");
        ((IProgress<int>)progress).Report(80);
        Bindng2DArrayToListview2_Run_Search(listview, itemsArr, maxColCount);
        EnableCreateSheetBtn();
        ((IProgress<int>)progress).Report(90);
        StatusText("Tidying up...");
        GarbageCollector(sourceWorkSheet.Item1, sourceWorkSheet.Item2, sourceWorkSheet.Item3, sourceWorkSheet.Item4);
        EnableItems();
        StatusText("Request Completed Successfully");
        this.createSheetButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(CreateSheetButton_Click);
        ((IProgress<int>)progress).Report(100);
        ((IProgress<int>)progress).Report(0);
    });
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is happening inside `TaskDialog`?

Comment: Are you set a breakpoint into `CreateSheetButton_Click`? Probably, your `async` method block the main thread. For this reason nothing happen while it works.

Comment: @Viewed , what will be the way to fix this in this situation?

Comment: @slugster It's similar to a messagebox.show() in wpf.

Comment: Try to begin from tutorial about `async/await`

Comment: I think click event setting part (this.createSheetButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(CreateSheetButton_Click);) should be out of the task or initializing part of the window. It can't work before the event is set with the function.

Comment: @dka: Please post the code for `TaskDialog.Show`as it's this method that is called.

Comment: Your code will throw `InvalidOperationException` because you try to access a GUI control from a non-GUI thread (by setting the `progressBar.Value` property from a `Task`-running background thread).